# WPF fade-in window animation using opacy is not very smooth at the first time

Tags: wpf, fadein, wpf-animation

I want to display a window using a standard fade-in effect. Everything works well but the first time I load and show the window the fade in animation is not very smooth. **If I close and show it again the animation works better**.

Any way to improve the fade-in at the first time?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;

namespace Kiosk
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan fadeTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
            var fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1d, fadeTime);
            BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, fadeInAnimation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you assured that it is not a reentrancy issue?  Does the same thing happen if you unwire the event after the first time?

Comment: I tried to "pre load" the window and put it on the background with Opacity=0. So I start animation on "Activated" event and the animation ia a bit smoother.